# Failed to create AppDomain "master.dbo[runtime].3372 - Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering if you have seen this error before?

This error appears in on my MAIN database server.
I do have other SQL Server having a LinkedServer connection to this Main server retrieving data. Whenever my stored procedure being executed at my LinkedServer, I saw this error appearing in my MAIN server.

Do you think some memory allocation issue that I need to configure on the MAIN server?

[image: error message]

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server is it? Currently supported Express editions cap buffer pool memory usage to ~1410 MiB.

Comment: It will be SQL Server Standard ... it will be either 2017 or 2019